# I keep getting 'Undefined: 1' Error in Node.js when trying to call a webAPI

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-web-api

Im currently writing some code to read a WebAPI.

C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX>node bot.js
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

```
at Object.parse (native)

at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\bot.js:82:20)

at emitNone (events.js:91:20)

at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)

at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)

at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)

at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Here is my code

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'backpack.tf',
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/IGetPrices/v4?key="personalapikey"',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body+=chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var price = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(price);
    });
}).end();
```

I am very new to node.js and coding in general.  But I have tried like 3 other ways of trying to get this to work.  I'm out of ideas

Comment: Please format your code, it's really hard read.

Comment: Anyway, them problem in `res.on('end'` callback, `body` is invalid json.

Comment: I reformatted, Can you explain a little more what that means?

Comment: That means that `body` is not valid json string (has incorrect structure or invalid chars). Add `console.log(body);` before `var price = JSON.parse(body);` and take a look at console output.

Comment: Just check what body contains, it's probably some error message, for some reason not as JSON ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add the following things to your code to make it more robust and error proof, check for the response code, check the body isn't empty, print body to the logs to make sure it's a valid JSON, and parse the body in a try catch in case the API respond with invalid JSON.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'backpack.tf',
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/IGetPrices/v4?key="personalapikey"',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body+=chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        if (res.statusCode == 200) { // Check the status code returned in the response
            try { // Add try catch block to handle corrupted json in response
                if (body != '') { // Check that the body isn't empty
                    console.log(body); // Print the body to check if it's actually a valid JSON
                    var price = JSON.parse(body);
                    console.log(price);
                } else {
                    console.log('Body is empty');
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Status code: ' + res.statusCode);
        }
    });
}).end();
```

Comment: It fixed the error!  The output is coming up as '301'

Comment: As a follow up question, how would I go about writing the Info from the api into a new .json?

Comment: If do you mean parse it to js int you can use: `var price = parseInt(body);` if you want to wrap it in a js object you can write `var obj = {price: parseInt(body)};`

Comment: I want the code to create a new .json file with all of the data from the webpage.  Im guessing i would use something like `js.writeFile`


EDIT: when trying to log 'price' it is returning 'Undefined'

Comment: You can write the data directly to files using the `fs` library. If it is critical to save it as JSON you need to create the object first and you can use JSON.stringify to convert the object to JSON string.

Comment: Im not sure what im supposed to be logging.  body returns nothing and price returns undefined

Comment: Hard to know what the problem without seeing the new code but I can guess that you are trying to save the file outside from the request logic. You should put the logic that save the JSON file in a function and call it from the `res.on('end', function() {`. This way you know you are saving the file only after you got the response...